# Dynamically created element is not firing click event in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events

I have many element called infoopts which are just a html i tags, which i attach an event listener to on click so that i can change their style (background color). These are being generated dynamically when i click on a button. I've tried a million things but for some reason none of them will fire the click event.
Here's what i tried:

```
    useEffect(() => {
    const infoopts = document.querySelectorAll('.infoopts')
        infoopts.forEach(el => {
          el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
              console.log('clicked') //never logs this 
              el.style.background = 'red'
          })
        })
  },[])
```

console is not even logging the click event. This is supposed to be an amateur issue. Why isn't it creating the click event?

2 Reasons why i am not using React:

1. I want to style also its neighbor element, onClick will only style that element
2. If i use state it will change ALL my elements that has infoopts class, i just want to style the clicked one and its neighbor (state is global)

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using react to do this for you? I don't think `.infoopts` will exist when the component is mounted, so your `querySelectorAll` finds nothing.

Comment: please enlighten me on how to use react to do this.

Comment: Take a read of https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html. Achieving this in your specific implementation would require knowledge of how those `.infoopts` elements are being rendered in the first place.

Comment: I cannot use the react standard way for 2 reasons: 
1. i want to style also its neighbor element 
2. if i use state it will change ALL my elements that has infoopts class, i just want to style the clicked one and its neighbor (state is global)

Comment: Ok. Consider adding this extra information to your question.

Comment: i just did. this is why i am using Vanilla to do this. But the Vanilla is not working

Comment: If not already, i think you are going to have use some state to track which items are selected.

Comment: how do i do that? Can you provide examples please

Comment: your issue is a little difficult to visualize, please provide a reproducible example in codesandbox or a github repo

Comment: <button>Add Element</button> - when you click this button, it adds an element with infoopts class. When i have like a few of them on the page, i want to click on any to change its color and parent container color for example. - That's all

Comment: you can find an example of how to track the selected items in any react todo list example you find googling, it's basically just having an array of items in the parent component, in this case an array for your infoopts elements

Comment: yes, that definitely sounds like a todo list

Comment: its not a todo list but i guess the same logic applies

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the code in your question is that `.infoopts` might not even exist when this component is mounted. In that case, `querySelectorAll` would find nothing and your event handler would never fire because it was never attached to anything.

---

Without knowing the source of your data, or what your component hierarchy looks like, below is one possible example of a naive implementation.

Hold onto some local component state to determine which item in the list is selected, and then render the UI from that state.

The rendered DOM nodes are simply a reflection of the component's state. To update any of the DOM nodes, simply update that state.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([
    { title: "foo", selected: false },
    { title: "bar", selected: false },
    { title: "buzz", selected: false },
    { title: "foo", selected: false },
    { title: "bar", selected: false },
    { title: "buzz", selected: false },
    { title: "foo", selected: false },
    { title: "bar", selected: false },
    { title: "buzz", selected: false }
  ]);

  const handleClick = (i) => {
    const updated = [...items];
    updated[i].selected = !items[i].selected;
    setItems(updated);
  };

  const determineBgColor = (i) => {
    const itemIsSelected = items[i].selected;
    const neighbourIsSelected =
      items[i - 1]?.selected || items[i + 1]?.selected;

    if (itemIsSelected) {
      return "darkred";
    } else if (neighbourIsSelected) {
      return "bisque";
    }
    return "darksalmon";
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ul>
        {items.map((item, i) => (
          <li key={i}>
            <button
              style={{ background: determineBgColor(i) }}
              onClick={() => handleClick(i)}
            >
              {item.title}
            </button>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit objective-hugle-q43ns]

---

Alternatively, the state might already be kept in a parent component. In that case it might be passed into this component as a prop, and this component is simply rendering based on the value of the data in that prop.

Then you would need to find a way to update the state in the parent component, and the changes will flow from the parent, to the child, and the rendered DOM will update accordingly.

Either way, the same principles apply. When using React you should aim to be writing declarative components that *react* to their state & props, as opposed to attempting to imperatively affect the DOM yourself.

---

I *highly* recommend that you read https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html if you haven't already.